# Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've an error in ionic when I try to build android!

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

but:

```
➜ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/amaitre/android-sdk-linux
```

and the command android work:
http://hpics.li/b1c351a

Answer (score 2):

Be careful if you sudo your ionic command !
Don't forget to add the path in your super user environment :)

Answer (score 1):

Download Android SDK Tools from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

Extract in: /home/{{user}}/build/

Insert below code at ~/.profile (caution: do not remove anything from there, just append this code)

```
//set PATH so it includes android SDK toold
if [ -d "$HOME/build" ] ; then
ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/build/android-sdk
PATH="ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
fi
```

Please let me know if this suggestion solved your problem.